# I want only one custom Toolbar for all activities I have tried many solutions but none of them worked

Tags: java, android, mobile

BASE ACTIVITY

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner main_spinner;
String[] OptionsSp = {"Identify Species", "Laws and Sections", "Court Details", "Investigating Officer", "Accused Information", "Offense Information",
        "Operation Detail", "Seizure List", "Arrest Procedure", "Bail", "Prayer",
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mytoolbar);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    main_spinner = findViewById(R.id.main_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter SpAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(BaseActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, OptionsSp);
    SpAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    main_spinner.setAdapter(SpAdapter);
}
}
```

CLASS WHERE I WANT TO GET THE CUSTOM TOOBAR

```
public class SpeciesAct extends BaseActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner main_spinner;
int pos = 99;
ImageView backbnofmain;
String[] OptionsSp = {"Identify Species", "Laws and Sections", "Court Details", "Investigating Officer", "Accused Information", "Offense Information",
        "Operation Detail", "Seizure List", "Arrest Procedure", "Bail", "Prayer",
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    }}
```

AND I AM NOT GETTING VALUES IN SPINNER ALSO
**NOTE:**  I don't want to use include layout in all activities because ,I want spinner filled only once and can be reusable in all activities from toolbar otherwise I have to find ids and do duplicate work everytime.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is a Single Activity Application, which it seems like, you might be better suited to using Fragments. That way you will have the Single Toolbar in your Activity, and fragments underneath it. Based on the Fragment you can also set different state in your Activity's Toolbar.

You can read about Fragments [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Comment: Yes But My App will work on offline completely and fragments are very confusing for that so I am using activity instead of fragment